# Getting ‘403 Authorization header not found’ when request a token

Tags: php, wordpress, api, jwt

I’m trying to get this plugin work on a blank WP.

```
.htaccess is set
wp-config.php is set
```

When I’m trying to get a token from `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token`
I’m getting this:

```
{
“success”: false,
“statusCode”: 403,
“code”: “jwt_auth_no_auth_header”,
“message”: “Authorization header not found.”,
“data”: []
}
```

my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/04/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /demo/04/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1 
</IfModule>
```

Any Help